# Java SpringBoot Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception, spring-boot

I'm writing a Spring Boot Application. And I'm implementing the exception handling right now.

I got the following problem.

My exception handlers look like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SpecialExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ResponseObject missingServletErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, MissingServletRequestParameterException exception) {

 //do something
return responseObject;
}}
```

And I got a general exception handler which looks

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralExceptionHandler {    

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public ResponseObject defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception)  {
// do something
return responseObject;
}}
```

But I got a problem: my application always runs into the GeneralExceptionHandler instead of the special handler unless I change the name of the GeneralExceptionHandler class to a name which comes alphabetically after the special exception handler (e.g. change 'GeneralExceptionHandler' to 'zGeneralExceptionHandler').

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding `@Order(N)` annotations on your `ControllerAdvice`s, to force their registration order (where N is a `int` defining the order)